# Valores de un Select con php

Tags: php, html

**¿Cómo hago para que me devuelva con un foreach los valores en un select?**

Tengo dos valores en mi tabla de Eventos en la columna estado_evento los cuales son *Iniciado* y *Finalizado*, como hago para que me de los dos ya que de esta manera solo me da un solo valor y no el otro.

De antemano Gracias.

Este es mi código:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="estado_evento">Estado del Evento:</label>
    <select name="estado_evento" id="estado_evento" class="form-control">
        <option>
            <?php echo $eventos->estado_evento?>
        </option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Como obtienes `$eventos` de donde sale?

Comment: de aca del controlador:

Comment: public function index()
 {
  $data  = array(
   'eventos' => $this->Eventos_model->getEventos(),
  );
  $this->load->view("layouts/header");
  $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
  $this->load->view("admin/eventos/list",$data);
  $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
 }

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a tu duda, de como iterar el contenido del objeto **$eventos**    para obtener los N valores del atributo **estado_evento**, podrías ayudarte con este bloque.

```
<?php
foreach ($eventos->estado_evento as $valor) {
        echo "Estado evento: $valor<br />\n";
} ?>
```

También es muy útil la [documentación oficial del PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/sdo.sample.getset.php)